# Split a Table to Format into Spreadsheet

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010, ole

I have a table, that has data like.

```
    ------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+------------+
    Agent Name  |   Total Fails |   To Process  |   Processed   |   Declined    |   Total Today |   Daily Net   |   Switched |  
    ------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+------------+
    John H      |       0       |       3       |       0       |       3       |       10      |       18      |       3    |
    Mary B      |       0       |       1       |       0       |       1       |       14      |       25      |       4    |
    Department  |       0       |       4       |       0       |       4       |       24      |       43      |       7    |
    ------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+------------+
```

What I would like is an **Embedded Excel sheet** in an **Access Form**. Added to the complexity, I need it to be organized in a different fashion. I need the Excel sheet to be in this format.

```
    Agent Name      |   John H  |   Mary B  |   Department
    ----------------+-----------+-----------+---------------
    Total Fails     |       0   |       0   |       0   
    To Process      |       3   |       1   |       4
    Processed       |       0   |       0   |       0
    Declined        |       3   |       1   |       4
    Total Today     |       10  |       14  |       24
    Daily Net       |       18  |       25  |       43
    Switched        |       3   |       4   |       7
```

So in simple terms I would want the first Column values in the table to be the Column headers in excel. The column names to be the First column of the Excel sheet. I am unable to explain exactly what I need.

I need to transpose the Sheet, not completely. Any ideas or thoughts?

Comment: It looks to me like a complete transpose.  Is it not?

Comment: Take a look at: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/182822

Comment: @Smandoli, yes actually looking at it, yes it is a complete transpose. Now my problem comes with Embedding this into an Excel OLE on the Access form.

Comment: @WayneG.Dunn, thanks for the link. I used it and it works beau. :) Could you please add it as an answer, so I could mark it as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is one example, from Microsoft, of how to transpose the data rows/columns in a table: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/182822

Titled 'ACCESS: How to Transpose Data in a Table or Query', it offers two methods:

- Method 1 - Transpose the Data in Microsoft Excel
- Method 2 - Use a Custom Function to Transpose the Table (includes sample code)

Glad it worked!

Comment: From [How do I write a good answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer): *"Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline."* - Please take a moment to [edit] your answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I would bring the data into a local table in Access and then bind your form to a [Crosstab Query](https://support.office.com/en-US/Article/Make-summary-data-easier-to-read-by-using-a-crosstab-query-8465b89c-2ff2-4cc8-ba60-2cd8484667e8?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US). Then the only code you need is the import from Excel to Access.

Comment: Hi, the method seems to be a bit complicated I am afraid. A simple transpose seemed to have sorted my needs (partially). Thanks for the response. :) Appreciate it.